# jeditable edit multiple links

Tags: javascript, jquery, inline, jeditable

Trying to make jeditable to edit multiple links, and update results onsubmit

```
function inlineEditData(linkId){
    $('.inlineLinkEdit_' + linkId).editable('crudDocumentationLink.htm', {  
        event     : 'editclick',
        submit    : 'Save',
        cancel    : 'Cancel',
        indicator : '<img src="images/indicator.gif">',
        width     : 600,
        onsubmit  : function(value, settings) {
            $('.inlineLink_' + linkId).href=value;
            $('.inlineLink_' + linkId).innerHTML=value;
            $('.inlineLink_' + linkId).show();
            $('.inlineLinkEdit_' + linkId).hide();
            $('.inlineLinkTrigger_' + linkId).show();
        },
        onreset  : function(value, settings) {
            $('.inlineLink_' + linkId).show();
            $('.inlineLinkEdit_' + linkId).hide();
            $('.inlineLinkTrigger_' + linkId).show();
        }
    });
}

function editLink(linkId){
    $('.inlineLink_' + linkId).hide();
    $('.inlineLinkEdit_' + linkId).show();
    $('.inlineLinkTrigger_' + linkId).hide();

    inlineEditData(linkId);

    $('.inlineLinkEdit_' + linkId).trigger('editclick');
}
```

And html:

```
<a href="${document.link}" class="inlineLink_${document.id}" id="inlineEdit_${document.id}">${document.link}</a>
<span style="display:none;" class="inlineLinkEdit_${document.id}" id="inlineEdit_${document.id}">${document.link}</span>
<span class="inlineLinkTrigger_${document.id}" onclick="editLink(${document.id})" style="cursor:pointer;">edit</span>
```

Editing working. But i want that value on the page updated according to user input. So what is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i managed to  do it (problem was in setting text correctly).
I changed "onsubmit" to "callback" and first two lines inside it.

```
$('.inlineLink_' + linkId).attr({"href":$('.inlineLinkEdit_' + linkId).text()});
$('.inlineLink_' + linkId).text($('.inlineLinkEdit_' + linkId).text());
```